# node.js + express error: Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am new to node.js. I was trying a script which is using express module.
  I have installed express, using,

```
npn install express
```

When I run the code I got the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined
at Function.app.use (c:\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:113:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (c:\node\uploadResize.js:13:6)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:901:3
```

How to solve this issue?

Here is my node script.

```
var http    = require('http'),  // Libraries
util    = require('util'),
fs      = require('fs'),
couch   = require('cradle'),
connect = require('express'),
endsWith,   // Internal Functions
determineMimeType,
upload;

connect()
.use(connect.bodyParser())
.use(upload)
.listen(3000);

upload = function (req, res, next) {
    // function body
}
```

Comment: What is the code which produces such error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign `upload` a value *before* passing it to `app.use`

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
  var hourMs = 1000*60*60;
  app.use(express.static('c:\\node', { maxAge: hourMs }));
  app.use(express.directory('c:\\node'));
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

the code not is npm install express ??

then the dir node_modules in the same dir in witch you have your app

C:\node\node_modules
C:\node\app.js